# Strange application of Stoke's Theorem

Tags: multivariable-calculus, line-integrals, stokes-theorem

[image: Problem]

This initially appeared to me to be a standard Stoke's Theorem problem. Upon trying to compute the curl, I ran into a complete mess that is seemingly unsolvable in any reasonable time frame.

Am I wrong in assuming that this is a Stoke's Theorem problem? I also checked to see if it was a conservative force field, which I did not find it to be. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the curl of $\mathbf F$?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown well it appears that somehow the cross product manages to clean up to a manageable curl of (-2z,-2x,-2y). When I was computing it I suppose I made some error that threw the whole thing off.

Comment: Note that when you compute the curl, both the $e^{x^2}$ and the $\sin(z^2)$ term disappear, so the curl should come out to something fairly nice.